# Passing information from one template to another

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I show list of available things in database against a search. Now i want to make each item fetched by database a link which can lead to another page and on that page i could show this chosen item in detail. So my problem is how can i pass this information from this page to the new page?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried please?

Comment: i am trying to pass the id of the item from template to URL and then by this id look in database  and show all the attributes.

Comment: I solved it by passing item id to url and then captured this id in my view and queried database to fetch information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the id of your item, so in the new page you can query again the database for more details.

if you use include tag you can pass object also:

```
{% include "url/to/your/template" with object=your_object %}
```

and then inside your detail's template you can call as usual

```
{{ your_object.detail }}
```

Comment: passing id is looking more appropriate for my problem. i am doing this in my template < a href="/traveler/ride-details/{{ride.id}}/"> and i get url "http://127.0.0.1:8000/traveler/ride-details/1/" and last number in url is id of item so now problem is how to pass this id to my view from url?

Comment: you have to use {% url "namespace:your/url/" ride.id %}